# Odd Indent Error With Coffee Script 1.6.3

Tags: coffeescript

I updated to the latest coffee script and still am getting the following error: Any ideas on what might be causing the error?

```
ie = (->
  undef = undefined
  v = 3
  div = document.createElement("div")
  all = div.getElementsByTagName("i")
    while div.innerHTML = "<!--[if gt IE " + (++v) +"]><i></i><![endif]-->"
  all[0]

  (if v > 4 then v else undef)
())
```

I've removed this line from a massive js file I'm converting to coffee script and it all compiles fine. Can anyone see what might be wrong with this?

```
SyntaxError: unexpected INDENT
>> On line: 816
>>     while div.innerHTML = "<!--[if gt IE " + (++v) +"]><i></i><![endif]-->"
>> ^
```

Comment: Why is the `while` indented? I'm having a hard time figuring out the intended structure of that loop.

Comment: @muistooshort the while in the source was odd, it wasn't of the shape `while (stuff is true) { do this other stuff}` it was `while (do this stuff)`. The source js looks really peculiar to me, I think that messed up the translator.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you got your JS to do this from [here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/detect-ie-in-js-using-conditional-comments/), then you have translated the **JavaScript** to **CoffeeScript** poorly.

What you want is something like this:

```
ie = do ->
  version = 3
  div = document.createElement 'div'
  all = div.getElementsByTagName 'i'

  testVersion = ->
    div.innerHTML = "<!--[if gt IE #{version}]><i></i><![endif]-->"
    all[0]

  while testVersion()
    version += 1

  if version > 4 then version else no
```

Comment: I actually used some of the tools out there to convert from js to coffeescript. It has worked in the past but this time I think it just failed miserably

Comment: @imaginethepoet I think the structure of the while loop in the source goofed up the translator. Not your fault. I can't figure out if it's "tricky" js or bad js. muistooshort will probably know.

Comment: @phenomnomnominal returning a number or a boolean seems odd to me. If you just left off else no you'd be returning undefined which seems fine since this is an IIFE.

Comment: The automatic translators are (AFAIK) all broken in "interesting" ways. I don't think they should be used at all: leave your working JavaScript as JavaScript or translate it by hand and learn something.

Comment: @jcollum, I guess I disagree. My assumption is that this would be used as something like `do something if ie`. And it shouldn't really be `undefined` because the IIFE has been evaluated and really should turn something, so an explicit `false` seems better.

Comment: I'll give this a try. Basically I got this from a dev. I didn't know that was the original source code (the link you provided).

Comment: @muistooshort in my experience these automatic translators save more time than they cost. You just have to be aware of edge cases like variable shadowing and this funky use of a while loop that isn't.

Comment: @phenomnomnominal I think the function could be aptly named `injectIeHtmlIfNeeded` and in that case you wouldn't care what it returned -- you'd just run it. No big.

Comment: @jcollum: In my experience, automatic translation is pointless at best: subtle hidden bugs get introduced into formerly working code, you learn nothing, your code doesn't get any better or become idiomatic CoffeeScript, and I don't even see any reason to bother.